# Classification of transitive subgroups of finite symmetric groups generated by double transpositions

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I want to classify (up to isomorphism) all transitive subgroups of symmetric group $S_n$ which are generated by double transpositions (product of two transpositions).  Is there a characterization for such subgroups of $S_n$?

Comment: Presumably you meant "product of two disjoint transpositions".

Comment: Babai proved that the minimal degree of a primitive group of degree $n$ that does not contain $A_n$ is at least $(\sqrt{n}-1)/2$, so it is easy to classify the primitive examples. Imprimitive examples must have blocksize $2$, so your classification will not be too difficult.

Comment: @DerekHolt In a single sentence you use twice the word "degree" in two meanings. In the first occurrence, what do you call degree?

Comment: @YCor Yes I guess I did! The minimal degree of a subgroup $G \le S_n$ is the smallest number of moved points of a non-identity element of $G$. So the minimal degrees of $S_n$ and $A_n$ are $2$ and $3$. The minimal degree of a group in the question must be $3$ or $4$. There are many results in the literature, going back to Jordan,  about the minimal degree of a primitive group. Unfortunately the degree of $G \le S_n$ has two different meanings in common usage. It can just mean $n$, or it can mean the number of moved points of $G$. For a transitive group these meanings coincide.

Comment: Babai's inequality then yields $n\le 81$ in the primitive case $\neq A_n$. What's a reference? (Googling 'Babai degree permutation group' leads me to other results)

Comment: The Babai reference is L. Babai, On the order of uniprimitive permutation groups, Ann. of Math. 113 (1981), 553-568. That does not use the classification of finite simple groups. There are more recent improved results that give more information, such as On the Minimal Degree of a Primitive Permutation Group, Robert Guralnick, Journal of Algebra 207, 127-145 (1998). There are also databases of primitive groups that can be used for groups of bounded degree. Since the OP wrote that (s)he wants to classify these groups, I don't want to do this myself!

Comment: two transpositions maybe disjoint or not. please give an appropriate reference if exists any

Comment: I have given references for the primitive case in my comments. The imprimitive case is easy because the blocksize must be $2$.